# Prove that $x^x-1\geq(x-1)e^{x-1}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality

Let $x>0$. Prove that:
$$x^x-1\geq(x-1)e^{x-1}$$

I tried to use the Taylor series, but I did not get a proof.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If we prove that $f(x)=(x^x-1)e^{1-x}$ is a convex function on $\mathbb{R}^+$ we are done, since $y=x-1$ is just the equation of the tangent at $x=1$. On the other hand
$$ f''(x)=\frac{e^{1-x}}{x}\left(-x+x^x\left(1+x\log^2 x\right)\right)\tag{1} $$ 
and $(1+x\log^2 x)\geq 1$, $x^x\geq x$, so $f$ is trivially convex on $\mathbb{R}^+$. Just to clarify: $x^x\geq x$ is equivalent to $\exp\left((x-1)\log x\right)\geq 1$, that is trivial too, since $x-1$ and $\log x$ have the same sign on $\mathbb{R}^+$ and $\exp$ is monotonic.